# Data exchange - Python and Fortran

Tags: python-2.7, fortran

We are developing a scientific application which has the interface in python 2.7 and the computation routines written in Intel Visual Fortran. Reading the source files is done using python, then only the required data for computations has to be passed to standalone Fortran algorithms. Once the computations done, the data has to be read by python once again.

Using formatted text files seems to be taking too long and not efficient. Further, we would like to have a standard intermediate format. There can be about 20 arrays and those are huge (if written to formatted text, the file is about 500 MB).

Q1. In a similar situation where Python and Fortran data exchange is necessary. What would be recommended way of interaction? (e.g.: writing an intermediate data to be read by the other *or* calling Fortran from within Python *or* using numpy to create compatible arrays *or* etc.)

Q2. If writing intermediate structures is recommended, What format is good for data exchange? (We came across CDF, NETCdf, binary streaming, but didn't try any so far.)

Comment: For data, I prefer HDF5.  Good performance, compression, library bindings for C, C++, Fortran, Python, Java, etc.

Comment: Also note that netCDF4 uses an enhanced version of HDF5 as the storage layer.  Python and Fortran have good libraries to handle netCDF4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way of wrapping Fortran code in Python is with [`f2py`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/) (included in the `numpy` module).

For the output of intermediary results, a number of formats could work, it really depends on your requirements.

- For simple datasets, from python, just use [`numpy.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html).
- If your datasets become large, HDF5 with, for instance, [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/) in Python and `libhdf5` in Fortran could be used.
- Otherwise, if you don't want to link your code to an external library,  custom binary files written from Fortran and parsed with `numpy` could work too.

Comment: I decided to go with hdf5 format because of its self describing, fast and I managed to configure it on python and FORTRAN. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would interface directly between Python and Fortran. It is relatively straightforward to allocate memory using Numpy and pass a pointer through to Fortran. You use `iso_c_binding` to write C-compatible wrapper routines for your Fortran routines and `ctypes` to load the Fortran .dll and call the wrappers. If you're interested I can throw together a simple example (but I am busy right this moment).